# Event Receiver Item Updated how find element to update

Tags: event-receivers, updatelistitems

How to find by code elements to update in Event Receiver ItemUpdated and to update them ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

they are already updated, thats why the event-receiver is triggered.

you can get the item, on which behalf the receiver is running by

```
properties.ListItem
```

(properties-object is received as parameter of the method)

however, if you update the item again, you have to be careful. because updating the item again of course triggers the Events again, this could get quite complex. Reconsider your architecture before doing so.

Comment: I must update a item in secound list on udpate in first list.

Comment: then you have to get the second list and find the item, either by ID or Query, depending on the way you designed the referencing of both.

Comment: And how add Query to the elements of the list in event receiver. Please help

Comment: build an query by using the SPQuery Object and then call getItems(query) on the list. You have to build the CAML-Query of course by yourself according to your needs. I don´t know how build your architecture to find get a reference to the item.

Comment: But how. Could You give a sample of Code ?